# Honda Accord Jerks when shifting gears and makes grinding sound?

Tags: honda, transmission, noise, shifting, accord

I have a 99 Honda Accord 2dr 3.0L V6 automatic.

When I drive this car it makes a whooooo sound coming somewhere from the engine, when I turn to the right it is intense and when I turn to the left it does not make that sound, this sounds like the bearings but its not.

The car when shifting gear feels like it disengages from the transmission (sort of goes into neutral) and than catches to the next gear, so it jerks badly. If you increase the speed steadily at a slow rate, it will not do that.

What could be the issue here? I have replaced the right engine mount, because this car has been in an accident (it hit a toyota pickup truck in the rear) so the mount was all bent.

Also, when standing without any movement and shitfting it into "D" it sort of takes a second for it to do it and than goes toodoo.

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level?

Comment: Alex, did it end up being low transmission fluid? My Honda Accord is doing the exact same thing. Seems pretty common fo these cars as I am googling it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like low fluid pressure, I would have your transmission looked at quickly. As for the noise when turning, it could be differential related.